# Android tab color not changing

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hi i'm trying to change the color of my tab widget but when i run the app it doesnt change does anyone know why?

heres my code where i try to change the color of my tabhost both unselected and selected

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666")); //unselected
        }
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // selected
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablayout);
            checkInternet();
            checkPreferences();

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
//        setTabColor(tabHost);


        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec resultsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Results");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        resultsspec.setIndicator("Results", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.miresults_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, MIResults.class);
        resultsspec.setContent(photosIntent);
//        setTabColor(tabHost);



        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec Fixturesspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fixtures");
        Fixturesspec.setIndicator("Fixtures", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mifixtures_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, MIFixtures.class);
        Fixturesspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        TabSpec tablespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Table");
        tablespec.setIndicator("Table", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mitable_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, MITable.class);
        tablespec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(resultsspec); 
        tabHost.addTab(Fixturesspec);
        tabHost.addTab(tablespec); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a drawable selector, similar to:

mytab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_v4" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_v4" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

to handle each of the states of the tab.  Each of the drawables, like tab_focus, is a 9-patch png.

You'll also need to override the tab layout to reference your drawable resource.  I'd use a style with a parent that references the android default, then override the background property to reference your "drawable/mytab".